# WSO2 ESB work with MB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm trying to send a message from a local client to ESB and redirect it to MB on the same server.
The message delieved MB. The client is waiting for response until application server throws error.

My environment as below
WSO2 ESB 4.8.0 (port offset 1)
WSO2 MB 2.1.1 (port offset 2)
IBM WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.1

The proxy service configuration of ESB

```
<proxy name="SMSQProdProxy" transports="http" startOnLoad="true" trace="enable">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                    <address uri="jms:/SMSQ?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&amp;java.naming.factory.initial=org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory&amp;java.naming.provider.url=repository/conf/jndi.properties&amp;transport.jms.DestinationType=queue"/>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
         </inSequence>
         <outSequence>
            <send/>
         </outSequence>
    </target>
    <publishWSDL key="gov:/trunk/services/SendToSMSQProxy.wsdl">
       <resource location="SMSWSService_schema1.xsd"
               key="gov:/trunk/services/SMSWSService_schema1.xsd"/>
    </publishWSDL>
</proxy>
```

jndi.properties

```
connectionfactory.QueueConnectionFactory = amqp://admin:admin@carbon/carbon?brokerlist='tcp://localhost:5674'
connectionfactory.TopicConnectionFactory = amqp://admin:admin@carbon/carbon?brokerlist='tcp://localhost:5674'
queue.SMSQ = SMSQ
```

wso2-esb-errors.log

> 2014-03-21 14:18:54,276 [-] [HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-1]  WARN SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-3

wso2-esb-trage.log

```
INFO TRACE_LOGGER Proxy Service SMSQProdProxy 
received a new message from : xx.xx.xx.xx
INFO TRACE_LOGGER Message To: /services/SMSQProdProxy
INFO TRACE_LOGGER SOAPAction:
INFO TRACE_LOGGER WSA-Action:
INFO TRACE_LOGGER Using the anonymous in-sequence of the proxy service for mediation
INFO TRACE_LOGGER Start : Sequence <anonymous>
INFO TRACE_LOGGER Sequence <SequenceMediator> :: mediate()
INFO TRACE_LOGGER Mediation started from mediator position : 0
INFO TRACE_LOGGER Start : Property mediator
INFO TRACE_LOGGER Setting property : OUT_ONLY at scope : default to : true (i.e. constant : true)
INFO TRACE_LOGGER End : Property mediator
INFO TRACE_LOGGER Start : Send mediator
INFO TRACE_LOGGER Sending message through endpoint : null resolving to address = jms:/SMSQ?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&java.naming.factory.initial=org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory&java.naming.provider.url=repository/conf/jndi.properties&transport.jms.DestinationType=queue
INFO TRACE_LOGGER SOAPAction:
INFO TRACE_LOGGER WSA-Action:
INFO TRACE_LOGGER End : Send mediator
INFO TRACE_LOGGER End : Sequence <anonymous>
```

error log of application server

> java.io.IOException: Async IO operation failed (3), reason: RC: 55

Thanks for any idea.

After added `<property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>` I get another error message

> 2014-03-26 22:17:23,354 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-15]  WARN AuthenticationHandler Illegal access attempt at [2014-03-26 22:17:23,0353] from IP address null while trying to authenticate access to service StatisticsAdmin
>   2014-03-26 22:17:23,354 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-15] ERROR AUDIT_LOG Illegal access attempt at [2014-03-26 22:17:23,0353] from IP address null while trying to authenticate access to service StatisticsAdmin
>   2014-03-26 22:17:23,355 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-15] ERROR StatisticsAdminClient Cannot get service stats for service SMSQProdProxy. Backend server may be unavailable.
>   org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The input stream for an incoming message is null.

There is a similar problem https://wso2.org/jira/browse/WSAS-1214

Comment: Are you sure that repository/conf/jndi.properties is properly configured ?

Comment: Dear Jean, I added jndi.properties on this post. Thank you.

Comment: Yohan, I'm not sure what issue you are trying to fix.  Is the message not making it to the MB?  Do you need to know how to resolve the client timeout?

Comment: Dear Chris. The MB did receive the message client sent out but the client didn't know the process was completed and still waiting for response from ESB until time-out. I'm not sure if there's anything missing so the response was not sent out from MB to ESB or from ESB to the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following after the OUT_ONLY property to your in sequence to return back to the client.  This property will force the ESB to respond back to the client with HTTP 202.

```
<property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
```

Comment: Chris, thanks for your reply. It works. I got new error messages and pasted it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yohan,
It seems the new error you are experiencing is not related to the MB integration flow. Have you accessed the management console after session timed out? Can you reproduce this problem continuously? OR is this just one time occurrence?

Comment: Charitha, I could reproduce this problem continuously. Yes, I accessed the management console before/after timed out. I can provide any detail of this issue if you needed.

Answer (score -1):

When you set the `OUT_ONLY` property to true you are saying that, you are not waiting the response after the proxy end. So, in `outSequence` remove the `send` mediator.

If you want to force the proxy to send the response to the client, remove the 
`Out_Only` property and, in `inSequence` section set this after `endPoint` mediator.

```
property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED"  value="true"  scope="axis2"  type="STRING"
```

In `outSequence` section keep the `<send/> mediator`...